# Word to describe a relationship betwen two tangentially related objects

Tags: single-word-requests

In the sentence "people who like apples also like swimming", is there a word to describe the relationship between apples and swimming? They're only related by the fact that people like both of them.

An alternative way of describing the relationship would be "appeal to the same demographic".

Comment: Positively correlated.

Comment: Trying for one word if possible - this is for a UI

Comment: 'Correlated' is usually sufficient, although 'Correlation does not imply causation'.

Comment: or just 'related'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few words come to mind, [associated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/associate#associate__1) and [correlated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/correlate):

> **associate**
>
> Connect (something) with something else because they occur together or
> one produces another

*"When dwarf faunas are found in the fossil record, they are invariably
associated with times of environmental stress."*

> **correlate**
>
> Each of two or more related or complementary things

*"Rodent studies have shown that antidepressants stimulate the growth of new neurons, and that this correlates with their mood-elevating effects."*

Comment: Thanks, associated seems to fit best. It's still a bit vague though I guess there really aren't any words to strongly describe the concept.

Comment: @rikkit - There *are* words to strongly describe the concept: **positively correlated** as given in a comment. The fact that you personally don't like them doesn't mean they aren't a perfect description!

Comment: @AndyT Firstly, "positively correlated" doesn't describe the relationship between the two objects very well - the relationship is that people *like* both of them. It doesn't seem right in the context of my original sentence... if A is +vely correlated with B, and B with C, it's wrong to say that A is +vely correlated with C. "Associated" (and indeed "correlated" on its own" are vague enough to handle the indirect relationship. As to why "associated" is better than "correlated" for me is that "associated" implies a stronger relationship. Secondly... the question is tagged "single word" :)

Comment: @rikkit - Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought that you wanted a word to describe that people who *like apples* also tend to *like swimming*; whereas (as I now understand it) you want a word to describe that people who like *apples* also tend to like *swimming*. So you want a single word for **appeal to the same demographic**? I think if you edit my words in bold into your original question (assuming they're right, of course!) you may get some answers from a different angle.

Comment: @AndyT Yeah, that's exactly right and a much better way of phrasing the question. I've edited it in, thanks

Answer (score 5):

If apples and swimming are only related by the fact that certain people like both, then, in a sense, they really share no link at all, but merely appear to do so. In such circumstances people sometimes say that there is a ***tenuous link*** between them.

> **Tenuous:** Very weak or slight
>
> - *'the **tenuous link** between interest rates and investment'*
>
> <sub>[OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tenuous)</sub>

Comment: The two things don't really share any links, true, but it just so happens that, for us, the most important aspect *is* that people who like one like the other :). Also I think "tenuous" has a disparaging connotation.. it's a polite way of saying the relationship is irrelevant